# Installation Mythbuntu 11.10 on 64bit Toshiba Protege

Tags: 11.10, mythbuntu

Started iso cd and installed...
then asked to restart from cd...
locked with instructions to chkdsk...
followed these instructions...
no jot...
also: can no longer access bios...

I want to get this running on 3 computers
This one - see above
I have 11.11 running on an old Toshiba 32bit, with a few issues... persevering
Old Lenovo Thinkpad... 
all installer, but, will not boot... 
I seem to have lost the bootstrapper...
Followed instructions from forum...
Problem is most likely my lack of knowledge rather than quality of instructions/information...

Can you help.

Comment: I use mythtv in regular ubuntu.  You don't need  the mythbuntu distro to use it.  I can't say what the problem is with your particular installation, but why not try a regular ubuntu or its variants install and install mythtv that way.

Comment: Try this little guide if you need help.  http://parker1.co.uk/mythtv_ubuntu.php

Answer (score 1):

User @Daffydack has answered in comments. OP's problem seems to be solved

> I use mythtv in regular ubuntu. You don't need the mythbuntu distro to use it. I can't say what the problem is with your particular installation, but why not try a regular ubuntu or its variants install and install mythtv that way.